# How to switch zxing barcode scanner in portrait mode

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I am already use guideline of issue 178 for convert it into portrait but its not works fine Camera open in landscape mode not change its view landscape to portrait

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting my point if we do the barcode portrait then it shows in landscape beacuse we place images and buttons then it display in landscape so we have to use issue 178 and also use  view inflater to inflate images.